# Running JRuby/Rails app "off-premises" using Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, heroku, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm running a JRuby/Rails app on my own app server.  I don't want to run my own Postgres boxes right now, and want to use Heroku.  So, I spun up some Heroku Postgres instances and can connect to them fine via Sequel, but am having a hard time with the "native" ActiveRecord access.

I've set the connection URL in an ENV variable as

```
WAREHOUSE_PG_URL='jdbc:postgresql://<instance>:<port>/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory'
```

Then, in my database.yml, I have:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_URL'] %>
```

This seems very cumbersome.  I tried just setting the `DATABASE_URL`, but that blew up with `IndexError: string not matched`, and if I just did

```
production:  <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_URL'] %>
```

That blew up with: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got :driver = )`

Migrations are giving me strange errors though:

```
% rake db:migrate
file:/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.15/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel19/kernel.rb:28 warning: unsupported exec option: close_others
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
/Users/me/code/Exchange/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:54:in `structure_dump'
/Users/me/code/Exchange/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:150:in `structure_dump'
/Users/me/code/Exchange/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:270:in `(root)'
/Users/me/code/Exchange/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:43:in `(root)'
/Users/me/code/Exchange/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:37:in `(root)'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Update: this is the actual code around that method that's blowing up:

```
  def structure_dump(filename)
    set_psql_env
    search_path = configuration['schema_search_path']
    unless search_path.blank?
      search_path = search_path.split(",").map{|search_path_part| "--schema=#{Shellwords.escape(search_path_part.strip)}" }.join(" ")
    end

    command = "pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f #{Shellwords.escape(filename)} #{search_path} #{Shellwords.escape(configuration['database'])}"
    raise 'Error dumping database' unless Kernel.system(command)

    File.open(filename, "a") { |f| f << "SET search_path TO #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path};\n\n" }
  end
```

Line 54 is the `command = "pg_dump.....` one

Update2: I also want to just throw an "I'm annoyed I have to use 'don't bother checking if certs are good' in this setup" in there, also.

Update3: I just looked closely at this and realized how weird it was:

```
% rake db:migrate
file:/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.15/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel19/kernel.rb:28 warning: unsupported exec option: close_others
E, [2014-11-13T15:45:49.482000 #86686] ERROR -- : ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist
  Position: 293:         SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
               pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum

I, [2014-11-13T15:45:51.671000 #86686]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateMarkets (20140312080145)
```

**CreateMarkets is my first migration** - I can't figure out where that code came from that rased the exception that happened right before it.  Also, that exception didn't stop the rest of the migrations from going....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to fix this by adding all of my database connection details to `database.yml`:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_URL'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_DATABASE'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_PORT'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_HOST'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RAILS_PG_PASSWORD'] %>
  ssl: true
```

So the ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter uses the url to connect (with all the ssl-cert-unchecking and all that), whereas the "regular" stuff that happens during the course of DB maintenance (pg_dump) will need to build their own set of ENV variables to control the execution of that command.  Neat.

I'm not "in love" with this, but it seems ok.